# Beginner question: returning a boolean value from a function in Python

Tags: python, function, boolean

I'm trying to get this rock paper scissors game to either return a Boolean value, as in set `player_wins` to True or False, depending on if the player wins, or to refactor this code entirely so that it doesn't use a while loop. 
I'm coming from the sysadmin side of the world, so please be gentle if this is written in the wrong style. 
I have tried a few things, and I understand TIMTOWTDI, and would just like some input.

Thanks.

```
import random

global player_wins
player_wins=None

def rps():

    player_score = 0
    cpu_score = 0

    while player_score < 3 and cpu_score < 3:

        WEAPONS = 'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'

        for i in range(0, 3):
          print "%d %s" % (i + 1, WEAPONS[i])

        player = int(input ("Choose from 1-3: ")) - 1
        cpu = random.choice(range(0, 3))

        print "%s vs %s" % (WEAPONS[player], WEAPONS[cpu])
        if cpu != player:
          if (player - cpu) % 3 < (cpu - player) % 3:
            player_score += 1
            print "Player wins %d games\n" % player_score
          else:
            cpu_score += 1
            print "CPU wins %d games\n" % cpu_score
        else:
          print "tie!\n"
rps()
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
   print "%s vs %s" % (WEAPONS[player], WEAPONS[cpu])
    if cpu != player:
      if (player - cpu) % 3 < (cpu - player) % 3:
        player_score += 1
        print "Player wins %d games\n" % player_score
        if player_score == 3:
            return player_wins==True
      else:
        cpu_score += 1
        print "CPU wins %d games\n" % cpu_score
        if cpu_score == 3:
            return player_wins==False
    else:
      print "tie!\n"
```

Comment: What boolean value should be returned for a tie?

Comment: Because it's inside a while loop, ties just dump you back at the beginning. REMATCH!

Comment: I take it this is not a good project to gain a proper understanding of programming?

Comment: matt, try doing projects that make you think more about the process.  Try the problems at Project Euler (http://projecteuler.net/) instead.

Comment: "I understand that TIMTOWTDI" - you must be confusing Python with Perl ;) "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it. Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch." (PEP 20 aka The Zen Of Python) ;)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ignoring the refactoring issues, you need to understand functions and return values.  You don't need a global at all.  Ever.  You can do this:

```
def rps():
    # Code to determine if player wins
    if player_wins:
        return True

    return False
```

Then, just assign a value to the variable outside this function like so:

```
player_wins = rps()
```

It will be assigned the return value (either True or False) of the function you just called.

---

After the comments, I decided to add that idiomatically, this would be better expressed thus:

```
 def rps(): 
     # Code to determine if player wins, assigning a boolean value (True or False)
     # to the variable player_wins.

     return player_wins

 pw = rps()
```

This assigns the boolean value of `player_wins` (inside the function) to the `pw` variable outside the function.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I got it, thank you. I will update this post to reflect the solution.

Comment: This code hurts my eyes... it ought to be `return player_wins`

Comment: Sure, Rafe, but that wouldn't be as clear for illustrative purposes.

Comment: It would be clearer to eliminate `if expression: return True`.

Comment: Okay, I added the idiomatic Python.  I still think it's less clear, because it requires more understanding of `return` than you can presume in someone who has never used it.

Answer (score 2):

Have your tried using the 'return' keyword?

```
def rps():
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

`

```
 def hit_cmpl(self):
        """To check if measured current is hitting the compliance. 
        if current hits the compliance, trip gets "1", otherwise '0'."""
        
        trip = self.keith2410.query(":sense:current:protection:tripped?")
        if trip:
            return True
```

`