# Issue in Boolean operation and bin built in function in python

Tags: python

I have some problem in understanding built in function in "bin". Please could anyone can explain in this , why i am facing issue. I'm beginner to python. 
[I have researched on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165933/beginner-question-returning-a-boolean-value-from-a-function-in-python), But i didn't find any relevant answer.

```
input = 12
mask = 13
expected_out =100

binIn = bin(input)
binMask = bin(mask)
binExpected = bin(expected_out)
print binIn ,binMask ,binMask  # 

if (binIn & binMask == binExpected): i want to do bitwise binIn & binMask and compare with  binExpected
    print "here1"
else:
    print "here2"
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Thanks in advance

Comment: The result of `bin` will be of type string. You are trying to do bitwise AND with two strings.

Comment: bin(input) of string will return string?

Comment: Yes, bin returns a str, why are you using bin?

Comment: @Sana What logic are you trying to achieve? (for example "to see if either option is equal to what is expected").

Comment: I want to compare 2 binary numbers.

Comment: compare two numbers after doing what to them?

Comment: I just added in the question , please have a look

Comment: @Sana, you realise 12 & 13 is not equal to 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *bitwise and* the ints and then call bin on the result comparing that result to `bin(expected_out)`

```
inp = 12
mask = 13
expected_out = 12

binExpected = bin(expected_out)

if bin(inp & mask) == binExpected:
     print("Here")
 else:
      print("Here2")
```

That all seems a but redundant considering you can compare the result to an int:

```
inp = 12
mask = 13
expected_out = 12

if inp & mask == expected_out:
    print("Here")
else:
    print("Here2")
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python `bin` function converts numbers to their binary representation strings:

```
>>> type(bin(1))
<type 'str'>
```

When you want to do binary operations (AND, OR, bit shifts and so on), you don't need to cast your integers to any other type. In your example, simply doing `input & mask` will work.

I don't quite understand what the `expected_out` value is though, since 12 & 13 (or 1100 & 1101) equals 12 (or 1100). Maybe you meant to write the expected value in binary? In that case, you need to write it as a string and convert it to an integer with `int` in base two:

```
input = 12
mask = 13
expected_out = '1100'

if input & mask == int(expected_out, 2):
    print "here1"
else:
    print "here2"
```